# eclipse xml validation, https certificate SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: eclipse, ssl, xsd, lemminx

I have a xsd schema on a local https server. The https server certificate is signed by the company root certificate chain. If I add:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="https://artifacts.../ConnPool.xsd"
```

I get the error:

Error while downloading 'https://artifacts.../ConnPool.xsd' to 'C:
\Users\xxxxx\.lemminx\cache\https\artifacts...\ConnPool.xsd' :
'[sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException] unable to find valid certification path to requested
target'.

I already added the lines:

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=WINDOWS-ROOT

to my eclipse.ini. Writing a small java program I have no issue to download the file with these parameters.

Is there another location to add the truststore parameters for lemminx?